# Apply style only if container has the scrollbar activated from the overflow-x: scroll

Tags: css, styled-components

I have a container with a bunch of divs that would overflow: scroll. I want to apply a border to a sibling button if the container scroll is activated. Is there a way in styled-components or css that I can accomplish this?

Comment: note that if you are using overflow-x: scroll then there willalaways be the scrollbar irrespective of whether the content is wide enough to need it. What you need to use is overflow-x: auto; which will only give the scrollbar if required. but i agree with the other answer -you will need js to determine the width of the element and compare it against the width of thecontaining element to determine if it is overflowing. then you can add aclass iff it is and use that for your styling

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this purely with CSS. You could determine if an element had focus or was being hovered on, then apply CSS that way (`:hover` or `:focus`). But you'd need to use a JavaScript `scroll` event to listen for scrolling on an element, then do something else.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event